# UIWebView issue with iOS 6

Tags: ipad, ios6, uiwebview

I have a running application in appstore which contains UIWebView. It worked perfectly fine till iOS 6.0. In OS 6 some hyperlinks are not working but the same thing is working fine when I use the safari browser in iOS on the iPad.

Do I need to add some extra delegate methods to make it working?
Currently I m Using following code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAuthenticationURL]];
[request setValue:[NSMutableURLRequest userAgentRequests] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&code=%@", username, password]
                             dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

delegate i have used:

1)

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

2)

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

inside this method I have used the following for loading data:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.reload = function(){};"];
```

3)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webViewshouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`
```

Do i need to implement some thing extra for make it working in iOS 6?

Any help is appriciated...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're having the same problem as described here: [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is not working in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704593/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-is-not-working-in-ios-6) or here [iOS 6 - UIWebView loadHTMLString not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466993/ios-6-uiwebview-loadhtmlstring-not-working-properly)

It seems iOS 6 loads and renders the page differently and could be stricter then 5

You could try to suppres iOS6's incremental rendering as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466993/ios-6-uiwebview-loadhtmlstring-not-working-properly)

> #### suppressesIncrementalRendering
>
> ```
> A Boolean value indicating whether the web view suppresses content rendering 
> until it is fully loaded into memory.
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL suppressesIncrementalRendering
> ```

---

You could also try to debug using your mac as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705041/672989):

> Additional tip: to debug javascript errors on iOS6, a new feature
> makes it very simple:
>
> - Go to the "Settings" application in your iPhone, enter the "Safari" settings and tap on "Advanced" at the bottom, then enable the "WebKit
>   Inspector" from there
> - Display your page to be debugged on the screen (i.e. launch your app and go to your screen that contains the WebView to make it visible)
> - Plug your iPhone to your Mac via your USB cable
> - Open Safari.app on your Mac, go to the "Development" menu *(1)*, select the menu item with the name of your iPhone and select your
>   application in the submenu.
>
> You will then be able to debug your web page presented in your iPhone
> using the powerful Web Inspector from your Mac, and can look into the
> javascript console, the DOM tree, etc.
>
> *(1) If you don't have the "Development" menu in Safari on your Mac, you can enable it in the "Advanced" preferences tab of the Safari
> application.*

More on remote debugging can be found [here](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers) (scroll all the way down to 'Remote Debugging') or [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=600) (WWDC video session: "Debugging UIWebViews and Websites on iOS")